# Unexpected Value Assignment Inside Function

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, vector, variable-assignment

In R: for the given dataframe

```
df <- data.frame('a'= c(1,3,5,7,9), 'b' = c(2,4,6,8,10), 'c' = c(1,2,3,4,5), 'update' = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I attempted to assign values to a column using a for loop as below.

**Example 1**

```
testFunction <- function(){

  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){   
    update_val <- df[i,]$a+df[i,]$b   
    df[c(which(df$c==i)),]$update <- update_val   
  }  
}

testFunction()
df$update
```

I then print the result, expecting to see `df$update` updated with the appropriate values i.e. `c(3, 7, 11, 15, 19)`. However the above still returns `c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA).`

Examples 2 and 3 below return the desired output.

**Example 2**

```
df$update <- df$a + df$b

df$update
```

**Example 3**

```
testFunction <- function(){

  update_val <- NULL
   for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
     temp <- df[i,]$a+df[i,]$b   
     update_val <- append(update_val, temp)   
  } 
  return(update_val)  
}

update_val <- testFunction()

df$update <- update_val

df$update
```

I just want to understand *why* Example 1 doesn't update the column/vector as expected?

Comment: It is updating the column, but the things that you do inside a function have no effect on objects outside the scope of that function. If you modify an object passed into a function and want to use the changed object, you need to explicitly return it.

Comment: For better readability, I'd recommend `df[i, "a"]` instead of `df[i, ]$a`

Comment: ...also, you have something very strange in your Example 3, where you start a for loop but then put a `return()` statement right at the end, which means that for loop will only ever execute once; as soon as it hits the `return()` statement, R will exit the function.

Comment: @joran is correct. Now you COULD use the `<<-` operator instead of `<-` but this operator has its own special place and shouldn't be abused. This operator recursively looks outside the current scope until it finds the variable in question to modify. `<-` only looks at the current scope.

Comment: @Sada93 I've heard(read) `assign`ing variables to the global environment isn't the best of practices.

Comment: It certainly isnt, just wanted to put it out there that it exists.